# if you have a circular reference of object,bit you no longer referenced it from an execution thread

Tags: collections, garbage

if you have a circular reference of object,bit you no longer referenced it from an execution thread,will this object be a potential candidate for garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

This is because garbage collection starts finding live object from a set of known root object. This list of root objects includes objects referenced from the stacks of running threads and the few other places (depending on the language in use)

If the object with the circular reference can not be reached from one of the root object then it will be eligible for collection.